# Win10 IoT weird boot

Tags: pi-2, boot-issues, windows-iot

I am running Windows 10 IoT on my raspberry pi 2. It was working fine until yesterday when I started getting this weird boot up...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qybXbeoHG6s

And then the screen goes black forever and I can't access the web admin tool.

Any ideas as to what is going on or how I can diagnose it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-imaged the SD card and it boots fine. Chalking it up to some Windows files getting corrupted or the SD card malfunctioning.